# How do cold/hot atoms move faster or slower than their thermal energy suggests?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have been frequently stuck on this question since first realizing it in the shower. While watching the hot water drop from the above shower head, and then watching cold water drop, I realize they both appear to be moving at the same speed.
This puzzles me, because I know that when an object is hot, its atoms are moving fast, or otherwise have energy that is propelling them to "move fast". Correspondingly, when an object is cold, its atoms are moving slowly, since they do not have as much energy to propel them to "move fast". I was wondering, if cold water appears to be moving at the exact same speed as hot water, then where does my misunderstanding come in? What law of physics and thermodynamics am I misunderstanding, or otherwise unaware of? Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bulk motion is generally unrelated to temperature; I could roll burning-hot and freezing-cold spheres over to you, and their kinematic behavior would be essentially identical.

Temperature broadly corresponds to atomic level motion around the center of mass. This motion, which is overlaid at the particle scale atop any bulk motion, is randomly directed and averages out to zero at the macroscopic scale, where it's undetectable.

(We might, however, expect the temperature dependence of viscosity to affect the motion of a liquid droplet.)